# Select specific li into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, click

I´ve a list in a div and I want to capture click event over a specific 'li' with jQuery.

My html structure is:

```
<div class="select area-select">
  <div class="texto-select">Área</div>
  <div class="lista-select lista-area">
    <ul class="ul-area">
      <li id="0" class="li-area">
        <div class="circulo" style="border-color:#18549c"></div>
        <div class="textodesplegables texto-area">Nombre del área</div>
      </li>
      <li id="1" class="li-area">
        <div class="circulo" style="border-color:#8bca5b"></div>
        <div class="textodesplegables texto-area">Nombre del área</div>
      </li>
      <li id="2" class="li-area">
        <div class="circulo" style="border-color:#f9a61d"></div>
        <div class="textodesplegables texto-area">Nombre del área</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to capture li click with:

```
$('ul.ul-area li').click(function() {
        $('.campos-para-filtrar').empty();
        filtroaniadir = $(this).attr("id");
        aniadirFiltro(filtroaniadir);
        cargarFiltros();        
    });
```

But when I do click on li, jQuery captures the `<div class="lista-select lista-area">` click and not the li click.

Can anyone give me any idea?

Comment: `aniadirFiltro();cargarFiltros(); `  what are these?

Comment: You need to pass the `click` event as an argument of your function. That event will have a `.target` property which will reference the clicked element. Use `.closest()` to find the `li` starting from the clicked element. Please note `.click()` is only a shortcut for `.on('click')`. I suggest you use `.on()` so you get better control over your event bindings.

Comment: Please take a read of the "*[mcve]*" guidelines; we can't see what's not working because we can't see the functions you're calling and we're missing the `.campos-para-filtrar` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `click` event will most likely happen on a child of the `li`. You need to first find the `li` with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). I also recommend using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.click()`:

```
$('ul.ul-area').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var li = $(e.target).closest('li'),
        filtroaniadir = li.attr('id');
    console.log('ID of li is ' + filtroaniadir);
    // ...
});
```

This way you only bind one click on the parent, instead of one for each child. Using the syntax above, your clicks will also work on any future `li`s you might add later on, using `$.ajax()`. It's an universal and robust construction which will work with any events, not just `click`s.

Answer (score 0):

Catch a reference to the element containing the `li` elements, then use `find()` function to catch all the `li` elements. Bind `click()` function to each of them and use `this` keyword to log specific id of clicked element by using `attr` function.

```js
$('.lista-select').find('li').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select area-select">
  <div class="texto-select">Área</div>
  <div class="lista-select lista-area">
    <ul class="ul-area">
      <li id="0" class="li-area">
        <div class="circulo" style="border-color:#18549c"></div>
        <div class="textodesplegables texto-area">Nombre del área</div>
      </li>
      <li id="1" class="li-area">
        <div class="circulo" style="border-color:#8bca5b"></div>
        <div class="textodesplegables texto-area">Nombre del área</div>
      </li>
      <li id="2" class="li-area">
        <div class="circulo" style="border-color:#f9a61d"></div>
        <div class="textodesplegables texto-area">Nombre del área</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a version without having to use jquery

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
   .forEach(function(li){
      li.onclick = function(e){ 
         // onclick code here 
      }
   });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it and works perfect, but I prefer do it with jQuery.